# How does one represent the range of Amazon Redshift's data type VARCHAR in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

According to [Amazon Redshift's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html) VARCHAR datum stores "4 bytes + total bytes for characters, where each character can be 1 to 4 bytes" which has range "65535 bytes (64K -1)".

However, what does this mean Python-wise? How can I represent this range e.g. in a Python script or in an XSD that is used in a Python script?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see an answer to this question by someone much more knowledgeable in Python in general, especially someone with a lot of expertise in CPython implementation. My understanding is the following.

Strings in Python 3 are sequences of Unicode code points, but only exclusively this. The memory allocation of different strings varies, for example:

```
sys.getsizeof('a') # returns 26 bytes
sys.getsizeof('ź') # returns 40 bytes
sys.getsizeof('Beautiful is better than ugly. Explicit is better than implicit.')
# returns 89 bytes
```

Python strings are, at least to some extent, unlimited in space they take in memory.

In CPython, strings also are, like almost everything, a [PyObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/object.c) object.
This means that beside the Unicode code points they also stores some overhead, for example number of references to a given string for garbage collection. They also has a pointer to a valid type object, which includes pointers to protocols (sort of abstract base class for all the strings). This allows Python strings to have many function pointers reflected in the interpreter in form of internal string methods that all string objects have out of the box (see for example `dir('')`).

Compare that with SQL databases as Amazon Redshift, in which 'a' string in VARCHAR(4) column take not more than, I guess, 3-4 bytes. Because a database is optimized to hold as little information per data entry as possible. VARCHAR *usually* holds 1 byte per character and 2 more bytes for the length information. That’s it, no further overhead for each data entry.

In summary it seems to me that comparing SQL database type with Python type is like comparing apples to oranges.

> where each character can be 1 to 4 bytes" which has range "65535 bytes
> (64K -1)". […] How can I represent this range e.g. in a Python script
> or in an XSD that is used in a Python script?

Django Object-Relational Mapper represents VARCHAR (models.CharField) as a simple string (str()).

If you need more you can check out SQLAlchemy’s [String/VARCHAR types](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/979ea6b21f71605314dc0ac1231dd385eced98c4/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py). But in the end those also are represented in Python code as a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't get too hung up on how Redshift stores characters.  A VARCHAR(10) can hold at most 10 characters.  This may be 10 1-byte characters but may be any number less than 10 of 1-byte characters.  It could be up to 3 4-byte characters but python won't care or even tell (without analyzing the characters) that these are different than 3 1-byte characters.